# Unable to open Corel Draw File

Tags: coreldraw

I have created a Corel Draw X5 file and saved it. Later I want to make some editing in it but I was unable to open it properly. When I open an corel draw file it`s opened with a single empty page with the name untitled-1. The size of file is more than 150MB. How can I fix this?

Comment: Check your file extension, is it proper?

Answer (score 0):

Corel files can be recovered from the system temporary files folder.

To open the temp folder, pick Start -> Run and enter `%temp%`.

You will find your Corel file in that folder. It will be prefixed with "Autosave____(your Corel file name)".